# Webkit Multicolumn issue on resizing

Tags: html, css, webkit, multiple-columns

I have a multicolumn element with two pharagraphs where in each of one I avoided the break in several columns. At the beginning they fill the two columns, one in each column. That problem is in webkit browsers, when I resize the window making it bigger (horizontal), in certain moment the two pharagraphs are displayed in only one column, and after that is imposible by resizing to have again the two columns filled. I need that regardless number and length of pharagraphs the pharagraphs spread in the two columns equally.

Here is a example in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L0ygp357/2/

```
.magazin-article-body {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -khtml-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -ms-column-count: 2;
    -o-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    .avoid-break {
        -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        break-inside: avoid-column;
    }
}
```

How can i avoid this problem using HTML/CSS?

Thank you very much